# getent groups shows AD groups, but getent passwd doesn't show users

Tags: active-directory, samba, winbind

Attempting to get my fedora linux machine to allow Active Directory logons, but I'm not aple to get past this.  I'm trying to reconcile a number of tutorials which seem to give contradictory advice as to a few things, such as setting + or / as winbind separator.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/winbind.html

http://blog.scottlowe.org/2007/01/15/linux-ad-integration-version-4/

I get about half way done and I never can get my active directory (win2k3) users to show up after getent passwd.

Comment: I had problems with winbind and switched to likewise-open, it's very easy to install. You can try to see if it works for you in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using nsswitch.conf?  If so, are the winbind entries in there correctly?

The winbind separator is a bugaboo because of naming conventions.  Yes, it can be made to work with a `\` instead of `+`, but there are consequences.  (Using `\` brings you closer to the old-style NT4 logins, which is what you're after).  Frankly, if you only have a single domain, I wouldn't bother with the winbind separator.  I would, however, set the default domain that winbind searches in.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `winbind enum users = yes` and `winbind enum groups = yes` set in [smb.conf](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html)?